# Setting language for apacite/bibtex

Tags: bibtex, languages, apacite

I have looked through other related entries but I can't find an answer to a seemingly simple question: How do I set the language for `apacite`, other than the `babel` default?

I am using BibTeX and not BibLaTeX.

For example, if I have `\usepackage[english, french]{babel}` French will be the default, and `apacite` takes it as the default, which seems sensible enough.

But I would like however my bibliography to appear in English. How can I tell `apacite` to select the `english.apc` file instead?

Note: The reason for this is that these commands occur in my personal `.sty` package file. I write documents in English or French, so I would like to pass an option to my package to select the right language, but I can't use `\usepackage` inside `\DeclareOption` apparently.

Here is the relevant code for my .sty file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypack}
%\DeclareOption{eng}{
%   \usepackage[greek, french, english]{babel}} --> THAT DOES NOT WORK
%\DeclareOption{fra}{
%   \usepackage[greek, english, french]{babel}}
%\ExecuteOptions{fra}

\usepackage[greek, english, french]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\endinput
```

Here is a sample doc file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{mypack}
\title{TEST}

\begin{document}
\maketitle  
Test document for language / bibliography:

\cite{kant1989}

\bibliography{Example_library}

\end{document}
```

Here is the bibtex file to make the example run:

```
@book{kant1989,
    title = {{Critique de la raison pratique}},
    author = {Kant, Emmanuel},
    editor = {Alqui{\'e}, Ferdinand},
    year = {1989},
    publisher = {{Presses Universitaires de France}},
    address = {{Paris}},
    isbn = {978-2-13-042461-1},
    keywords = {Read},
    language = {French},
    originalyear = {1790},
    translator = {Picavet, Fran{\c c}ois}
}
```

You will see in french appear, for example: `Oeuvre originale publiée en 1790`, while if I switch the order of french and english in the babel option it will read `Original work published 1790`.

Comment: You should provide a small complete document. That makes it much easier to test possible solutions. Regarding your remark about the option: you can e.g. set a boolean in \DeclareOption, and then use it to load the package later.

Comment: You can also set up key values to pass language options to babel.

Comment: Thank you. I saw this option somewhere as a workaround for not being able to require a package inside an option, but I thought there could be a simpler solution. Else yes, I will define this variable.

Comment: Another option is to delay the code with `\AtEndOfPackage`.